# the running time is small than TICK_time ,why it seized by barad_agent?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler, cfs

the CONFIG_HZ=250, i think the processor running time should  > tick cycle ( > 4ms) but why the stress 4132364 only running 996us then seized by barad_agent ?

[image: cpu used]